Context Menu positioning within scrollable element (angular)
I'm using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to display a large list of elements like below
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="115px" class="scrollable-card">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let project projects">
   <app-project-card [project]="project"></app-project-card>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

I have a contextmenu defined in app-project-card component like below
<mat-card class='project-card' (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">
  //other elements inside which are irrelavant
</mat-card>

<div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed;" [style.left]="menuTopLeftPosition.x"
  [style.top]="menuTopLeftPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="onEdit(project.id)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>Edit</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="onDelete(project.id)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>Delete</button>
</mat-menu>

Below is my code for onRightClick function.
onRightClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the browser's default context menu
    // Set the position of the context menu
    this.menuTopLeftPosition.x = `${event.clientX}px`;
    this.menuTopLeftPosition.y = `${event.clientY}px`;
    // Open the context menu
    this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
  }


The problem I'm facing is that my context menu isn't displayed on the correct coordinates. The coordinates seem to be calculated relative to the viewport, I'm not sure.
Scrolling the viewport changes the value of how much the y cordinate is off. x cordinate stays the same but is off. Let me know if you need more context. Thank you

If you provide any reproduceable example or just provide jsfiddle or code pen then it will be lot useful.

I feel that your .html can be like
<mat-card class="project-card">
  <mat-card-content>
    {{data()?.name}} {{data()?.id}}
    <div
      #menuTrigger="cdkContextMenuTriggerFor"
      class="fill example-standalone-trigger"
      (mouseup)="open(menuTrigger)"
      [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
    ></div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>

<ng-template #menu>
  <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu (closed)="open(null)">
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Refresh</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Settings</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Help</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Sign out</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

where
  .fill{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
  }
  .mat-mdc-card{
    position:relative;
  }

And
export class CardComponent {
  data = input<{ id: number; name: string }>();
  menuOpened = output<CdkContextMenuTrigger | null>();
  open(menu: any) {
    if (menu)
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.menuOpened.emit(menu);
      });
    else this.menuOpened.emit(null);
  }
}

I made that when a menu is opened/closed emit the trigger to allow close when we scroll (really I crazy because not work for me (opened) and (closed) events.
the "parent" like
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport" #scroller>
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">
    <app-card [data]="item" (menuOpened)="trigger=$event" />
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

And
  trigger!: CdkContextMenuTrigger | null;
  @ViewChild('scroller', { static: true }) scroller!: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
  items: any[] = Array(100)
    .fill('')
    .map((x, index) => {
      return { id: index, name: 'name ' + index };
    });
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.scroller
      .elementScrolled()
      .pipe(filter((_: any) => this.trigger != null))
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.trigger?.close();
        });
      });
  }

the stackblitz
